# Using Lan Management port - which kind of switch for remote control?

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network

I have no expertize in server hardware, however i have some IBM X3550 7978 and HP DL 160/G6 servers with 2 Lan ports, and a management port (that seem to be another Lan port).

Have anyone tried to use the management to control remotely the low level functions of the servers (reboots for example) ?
Which kind of switch or other devices have you used for this?
thank you

Massimiliano

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The management port you're talking about is commonly known as the iLO port on HP hardware, and provides a number of different features, like power control, reboot, sometimes KVM and serial console redirection.

The switch you use isn't that important, but I do tend to use a managed switch, so that I can put the management ports on a separate VLAN to the other traffic on the network.  This means that the ilo IP addresses can be handed out by a static lease DHCP server (give it the MAC address of the iLO controller, so it always gets the same IP address (for server 4, for example), gets 10.0.10.4, on VLAN 10.  Then have a private DNS server so that server4.ilo.mydomain.com resolves to 10.0.10.4.

Comment: +1 Virtually identical to how I set mine up.